# Vue 3 Vite and ZoomSDK

Tags: vue.js, vite, zoom-sdk

I’m having problems implement the zoom meetings sdk with vue 3 and vite. This is a boiler plate init of vue 3 project using the vue-create cli

I’ve also resisted my add with zoom and the my sdk key and sdk secret.

Following the steps in the zoom dev site I’ve installed the zoom meeting sdk with

```
npm install @zoomus/websdk --save
```

Following various example from the zoom dev site and zoom git I added this import to a the base HelloWord.vue component. This first error it get is

```
import { ZoomMtg } from "@zoomus/websdk";
```

Error

```
Uncaught TypeError: c2 is not a function
```

After seachinig for Similar problems I found a solution to this and change the import to this which gave no errors

```
import ZoomMtg from "@zoomus/websdk/dist/zoomus-websdk-embedded.umd.min.js";
```

The next bit of code I got from the zoom meet sdk vue 2 example

```
ZoomMtg.setZoomJSLib('https://source.zoom.us/2.8.0/lib', '/av');
```

However this produced another error

```
Uncaught TypeError: ZoomMtg.checkSystemRequirements is not a function
```

At this point I’m stuck.

I’m trying to create a zoom component that can be used on multiple pages however I can’t seem to get passed this early stage.

Help would be much appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

- As you wish you can create **client** view using embedded.

you can import   `ZoomMtgEmbedded from '@zoomus/websdk/embedded';`

```
import ZoomMtgEmbedded from '@zoomus/websdk/embedded';
    export default {
      created () {
      },
      data () {
        return {
          client: ZoomMtgEmbedded.createClient(),
          // This Sample App has been updated to use SDK App type credentials https://marketplace.zoom.us/docs/guides/build/sdk-app
          sdkKey: "",
          meetingNumber: "123456789",
          passWord: "",
          role: 0,
          signatureEndpoint: "",
          userEmail: "",
          userName: "Vue.js",
          // pass in the registrant's token if your meeting or webinar requires registration. More info here:
          // Meetings: https://marketplace.zoom.us/docs/sdk/native-sdks/web/component-view/meetings#join-registered
          // Webinars: https://marketplace.zoom.us/docs/sdk/native-sdks/web/component-view/webinars#join-registered
          registrantToken: ''
        }
      }
    }
```

[here](https://github.com/zoom/meetingsdk-vuejs-sample/blob/master/src/components/HelloWorldNew.vue) is full example updated recently.

- If you would like to use **component** view, you should add lodash
  script in `index.html`.